# How does one efficiently read and write large JSON files in python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have been trying to read and write a large JSON data file. Python's built-in `json` library is quite slow, and when I try to read a large json file, I am getting `MemoryError`

Comment: How large is "*large*"?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with python’s `json` module is that it is pure-python, and so it ends up being quite slow on large JSON files. You probably want to use [ujson](https://pypi.org/project/ujson/), which is written in C/C++ and compiles to native machine code.

Comment: I tried `ujson` which is really faster than `json` but when I try to read a large json file, I am running into `MemoryError`

Comment: How large is `large` ?

Comment: Tried reading 500MB json file (expecting to read max of 1GB file)

Comment: How much memory does your computer have, and do you have swapping enabled? I 500MB file might have 10M-50M individual integers, and each one will require 24 bytes; each string will take a minimum of 37 bytes. See https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understand-how-much-memory-your-python-objects-use--cms-25609

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of libraries is available for file handling one of my favorite is "Panda".
This tutorial might be helpful.
https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-json-tutorial/

and official documentation is always the best.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html